# How to find the magnitude of the sum of two vectors, given each individual vectors' magnitudes?

Tags: vectors

I have two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ such that:

$$
\lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert = 7; \quad \lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert = 16; \quad \lvert \mathbf{a - b} \rvert = 20.
$$

How could I use this to find $\lvert \mathbf{a + b} \rvert$? I have no idea of how to start either.

Comment: Do you know the dot product between two vectors?  And do you know how it is related to the magnitude of a vector ?

Comment: Draw a parallelogram.

Comment: @HosamHajeer I'm aware of the dot product and its formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $\bar a\cdot\bar a=|a|^2$

So
$$
\begin{align}
(\bar a-\bar b)\cdot(\bar a-\bar b)&=|a-b|^2\\
|\bar a|^2+|\bar b|^2-2\bar a\cdot\bar b&=400\\
-|\bar a|^2-|\bar b|^2-2\bar a\cdot\bar b&=400-2|\bar a|^2-2|\bar b|^2\\
-|\bar a+\bar b|^2&=400-2(49)-2(256)\\
|\bar a+\bar b|&=\sqrt{210}
\end{align}
$$